# "have a broadcast out on"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"
We have a broadcast out on Carly Beck’s vehicle.
No known employer.
"

What 'have a broadcast out on' means?
It means they openly search for Carly Beck/and her vehicle?

And there is another meaning for 'employer' besides 'boss'?
I can't understand what 'employer' means in this context.

FYI, they are police officers.

Answer (score 3):

It's police [jargon](https://www.bing.com/search?q=jargon&src=IE-TopResult&FORM=IETR02&conversationid=&adlt=strict).

> Jargon - special words or expressions that are used by a particular profession or group and are difficult for others to understand

Broadcast out = a message has been sent via police radio to everyone on patrol to look for Carly Beck's vehicle. It would be known as an [All-points bulletin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-points_bulletin) or BOLO/BOL (be on the look-out) today.

> An all-points bulletin (APB) is a broadcast issued from any American or Canadian law enforcement agency to its personnel, or to other law enforcement agencies. It typically contains information about a wanted suspect who is to be arrested or a person of interest, for whom law enforcement officers are to look.
>   An all-points bulletin can also be known as a BOLO or BOL, which stands for "be on (the) look-out".

Carly Beck has no known employer